# Check Rails application with Nagios

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, session, request, nagios

I want to check my rails-website with a simple nagios URL check. The problem is, that on every GET request from Nagios (every minute), a new session will be inserted in the `sessions` table. How can I prevent rails from generating new records for the Nagios queries?

Comment: what version of rails are you running? session stuff changed a fair bit between v2.x and v3

Comment: Have you considered using a cookie based session store instead of the database store in your application? If you really have to a use database store, a workaround would be to periodically clean the sessions table with rake db:sessions:clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this would be to create a NagiosController which does the testing you require. Just make sure that controller and its associated views never access the session object, and it [never gets loaded](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)

Of course, this might still create db records - not sure, haven't tested. 1 db insert a minute isn't going to kill the system though, and if you clear out sessions as per @eugen's comment aboe, you should be fine. I would think clearing them hourly would more than suffice.

edit: according to the [ActionController::Base APIdoc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html), you could also call `reset_session` (at the end of your action, I guess), which "removes the entire session"

Comment: `reset_session`doesnt work here because itself creates a session row and set its value to "`nil`". The trick is to call an action but don't call any session stuff or render a full blown view. I just create an action which returns "true".